# Kafka-connect elasticsearch auto-lowercase topic name for for index

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using **elasticsearch sink kafka-connector** to index messages from multiple kafka topics to elasticsearch. 
I have my topics with camelCase naming, and I can't change it. So when starting up the ES sink connector, it does not index anything because elaticsearch has problems with non-lowercase index names.

I know I can use `topic.index.map` property to manually convert topic name to index.
`topic.index.map=myTopic1:mytopic1, myTopic2:mytopic2,...`

Is there a way to convert **to lowercase automatically?** I have dozens of topics to convert, and I suspect it to be around hundred soon.

Comment: Not sure how to automatise his, but you can have upper letter in alias, so maybe you could create a mapping between alias (with upper) and generated lowercase index ?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that since `5.1` they do that automatically, if mapping is not specified for the topic.
[from here](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchWriter.java#L314):

```
final String indexOverride = topicToIndexMap.get(topic);
String index = indexOverride != null ? indexOverride : topic.toLowerCase();
```

See [this commit](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/commit/0696298f0dc8ebdbf7e2cc4e1ab061d7e291615f) for details.

Answer (score 1):

As of recent versions of the Elasticsearch sink connector this is done automatically. The PR that fixed this was https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/pull/251